# Nodejs connect-flash | Passportjs pass different message type instead of 'error'

Tags: node.js, passport.js, connect-flash

I want to pass different message type because im using bootstrap 4x it doesn't have alert alert-error. How would you change it? 
[passport.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYHja.png)

Answer (score 0):

The way i solved it might not be the best.

In css i added .alert-error class with bootstraps alert css this way i can manipulate 'error' looks.

[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKQPV.png)